# How to make ansible to consider configuring some hosts as optional?

Tags: ansible

I have two groups of hosts, mandatory and optional ones. The optional ones can go up/down for various reasons and I don't really care if playbook fails for those, but I do care about the mandatory ones.

How can I write a playbook that configures all hosts but returns failure (exit code), only if there were failures on the mandatory hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Hi try using separate blocks for optional ones and mandatory ones distinguished with when condition to match ansible.hostname and add ignore_errors : yes in the optional hosts block.